# Is on the earth grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Since the earth is a surface, like when we say

> There is a picture **on** the wall.

Can we say, for example:

> He's the most talented living human on the earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about [Earth as an object](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_START_%20earth%20is%20the%2C%20_START_%20the%20earth%20is%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_START_%20earth%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_START_%20the%20earth%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0), we have a slight preference for using it with a definite article "the earth is...".

When we are talking about [Earth as a place](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human%20on%20earth%2Chuman%20on%20the%20earth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuman%20on%20earth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%20on%20the%20earth%3B%2Cc0), we have a strong preference for using it without a definite article, for example "... human on Earth".

When we talk about ".... the .... on Earth", we are talking about it as a place, rather than a surface so, in my opinion, it is better without a definite article.

You can talk about something being "on the earth", but that makes me think of it as a surface made of soil, not the planet, for example:

> .. scatter the seeds on the earth.